# Calculus on complete fields of positive characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

Are there complete fields of positive characteristic with non-trivial absolute value? What does calculus on them looks like? I'm aware that they have to be non-archimedean, and that the bulk of results about power series convergence will carry over, but surely there have to be some extremely weird results e.g. local expansions will be ambiguous.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_analysis

Comment: The field of quotients of the ring of formal power series over a finite field is an example of such a field (the link given by @MarcvanLeeuwen seems to be about characteristic zero only).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for that precision; I had been a bit too quick in posting that. I do think that the study of such fields as you mention are generally considered to be part of $p$-adic analysis.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You mean $k[[X]]$ with the usual non-archimedean absolute value? Where can I read about calculus on this thing?